# is there anyway i can refresh spotify token in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, request, spotify

I create a function that I can log in to my Spotify and get the access token and I create a function to refresh my token but it does not work properly when I pass it to the request function with Axios and it returns 400 or 404.

what should I do ?

here is my code :

```
    const AUTH_URL =
  " https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize?client_id=MY_ID&response_type=token&redirect_uri=http://localhost:3000/&scope=user-read-playback-state";

let Login = () => {
  const spotifyHandle = (params) => {
    const afterHashtag = params.substring(1);
    const param = afterHashtag.split("&");
    const paramsSplit = param.reduce((Para, currentPara) => {
      const [key, value] = currentPara.split("=");
      Para[key] = value;
      return Para;
    }, {});

    return paramsSplit;
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (window.location.hash) {
      const { access_token, expires_in } = spotifyHandle(window.location.hash);
      localStorage.clear();

      localStorage.setItem("accessToken", access_token);
      localStorage.setItem("expiresIn", expires_in);
    }
  });

  return (
    <div>
      <a href={AUTH_URL}>
        <button>Login</button>
      </a>
    </div>
  );
};
```

here the refresh function:

```
let refresh = async () => {
  const clientId = "id";
  const clientSecret = "secret";

  const headers = {
    headers: {
      Accept: "application/json",
      "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    },
    auth: {
      username: clientId,
      password: clientSecret,
    },
  };
  const data = {
    grant_type: "client_credentials",
  };

  try {
    const response = await axios.post(
      "https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token",
      qs.stringify(data),
      headers
    );
    console.log(response.data.access_token);
    return response.data.access_token;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};
```

Comment: Inspect the request in the browser's dev tools and check whether it's in the exact format required by the Spotify API.

Answer (score 0):

The Spotify API follows the OAuth 2.0 specs and it requires (as presented at this [Spotify's documentation](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/general/guides/authorization-guide/#2-have-your-application-request-refresh-and-access-tokens-spotify-returns-access-and-refresh-tokens) section):

- `grant_type` to be equal to `authorization_code`
- `code` to be equal to the authorization code returned from the initial request to the Account `/authorize endpoint`
- `redirect_uri` `This parameter is used for validation only (there is no actual redirection). The value of this parameter must exactly match the value of redirect_uri supplied when requesting the authorization code.`

And a `Authorization` is also required at the request header, as stated at the docs:
`Base 64 encoded string that contains the client ID and client secret key. The field must have the format: Authorization: Basic *<base64 encoded client_id:client_secret>*`